# WebStorm Typescript map Promise.All doesn't resolve type automatically

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await

The problem is that it forces me to specify type in Promise.all when it actually could resolve type automatically.
getSquares3 works perfectly. getSquares doesn't work without specifying generic argument.
I'm using WebStorm and 2.0.6 TypeScript. The code actually can be compiled, but WebStorm complaints on the last line where return statement.
Code speaks thousand words.

```
interface IFoo{
    square:number
}
(
    async () => {

        async function square(i:number) : Promise<IFoo>{
            return Promise.resolve({square: i*i});
        }

        async function getSquares3(): Promise<IFoo[]>{
            //I like this as I don't need to use Promise.all<IFoo>
            var squares = await Promise.all([square(1), square(4)]);
            return squares;
        }

        async function getSquares(): Promise<IFoo[]>{
            var promises = [1,2,3].map(n => square(n));
            //I don't like this as I have to use Promise.all<IFoo>
            var squares = await Promise.all<IFoo>(promises);
            return squares;
        }

        squares = await getSquares3();
        squares.forEach(s => console.log('square:' + s.square));


        var squares = await getSquares();
        squares.forEach(s => console.log('square:' + s.square));

    }
)();
```

Comment: And, what is your question? If it's a TypeScript compiler problem, submit a RFE to the TypeScript project. If it's a WebStorm issue, submit an RFE to WebStorm.

Comment: Question how to make without generic argument?

Comment: As I said: if TypeScript compiles it and WebStorm complains, then just ignore the WebStorm error and submit an RFE to WebStorm. If TypeScript doesn't compile it, then submit an RFE to TypeScript.

Comment: I'm getting no errors from your code in webstorm. What's the error message that you're getting? Are you sure that webstorm is using a custom typescript version 2.x and not the bundled 1.8?

Comment: When I compile using tsc file.ts --target ES6  I don't get anything. So it is unlikely that this is TypeScript issue, but may be I need to use option to get detailed log. I did not find that option.

WebStorm gives me:
TS2322: Type 'Promise<IFoo>[]' is not assignabe to type 'IFoo[]'. Type 'Promise<IFoo>' is not assignable to type 'IFoo'.

Comment: Are you sure that webstorm is using the same typescript as you do (when you use `tsc`)? Check in `Settings` > `Languages & Frameworks` > `TypeScript` > `TypeScript version`. Also, can you post your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @Nitzan thank you very much. WebStorm was using Typescript 1.8.x. When I specified 2.0.6 it started to work.